# php add two options to variable

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have this code ->

```
<?php

$savearray = $this->savedlist;
$selectdata = new stdClass;
$selectdata->id='';
$selectdata->title=JText::_('BLA_BLA_BLA');
array_push($savearray, $selectdata);
$savearray = array_reverse($savearray);
echo JHTML::_('select.genericlist',$savearray,'savedlist','class="inputbox"','id','title','');

?>
```

I want to add to `$selectdata->title=JText::_('BLA_BLA_BLA');`

this code `echo count($this->savedlist)`

so what I want to achieve is something like ->

```
$selectdata->title=JText::_('BLA_BLA_BLA') . echo count($this->savedlist);
```

It doesn't work like `$selectdata->title=JText::_('BLA_BLA_BLA') . echo count($this->savedlist);` , can somebody PLEASE help me, how can I add the "count" code near the "BLA_BLA_BLA" text..?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `echo` inside string concatenation. `echo` will output string, and you wan't to assign function return value to another variable.

`$selectdata->title = JText::_('BLA_BLA_BLA') . count($this->savedlist);`